# Please help. A batch Script that check multiple factors and decide whether to install or not

Tags: batch-file, installation

I have been tasked to create a script that checks if .net framework 4.5 is installed before being installing a security program " Heimdal " and if there is no .net install it should install .net and then install Heimdal afterwards. I have tried different solutions but i can't get it to work...
Where have i gone wrong ?

```
REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client" /s|FIND "4.5"
IF %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 (
    ::echo.>DotNet4.5 already installed.txt
GOTO :Heimdal
) else (
    Start /B /I /WAIT O:\it\Patrick\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe /q /norestart
    echo.>DotNet4.5 Installed.txt 
GOTO :Heimdal
)
:Heimdal
    IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Heimdal"(
    echo.>Heimdal already installed.txt
GOTO :END
) else (
    msiexec /qn /i "O:\it\Patrick\Heimdal.msi" heimdalkey="xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx"
)
:END
    echo.>DotNetAndHeimdalInstalled.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about further errors in the code but the line

```
Start /B /I /WAIT O:\it\Patrick\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe /q /norestart
```

can't work. The `START` command supports either `/B` or `/WAIT` as option. Combination of there two switches won't work.

Comment: Thx Michael, thats been fixed. but yea it still dosent work. Is there a good method to troubleshoot it ?

Comment: I'd add an echo message to each section of your code so you can check where it craches and which logical path the execution takes. Test your fragments one by one. Are you sure that the .NET checkup works properly? Is there possibly an access violation when you try to create  text files like `DotNet4.5 already installed.txt`? And by the way, you should surround all paths and files with quotation marks when they contain spaces. Try "DotNet4.5 already installed.txt" instead! This also might help! :D

Comment: i'am local administrator so i should have write rights. i will try with the echo on the lines. And i inserted the quotation marks :D thx haha. im pretty newbie at this so it's kinda challanging :p.

Comment: you did not finish your FIND command. See FIND /? Add a string in quotes.

Comment: Also, on your next post... explain WHAT does not work? What results do you get?